# Derivative of $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Can someone help with any hints or a proof to this question?

> **Question.** Suppose $n>0$, $r>0$, and $0<\theta<2\pi$. Define $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $$f(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))=r^n \cos(\theta) \ \text{ and } \ f(0,0)=0.$$ Determine for which $n$, $f$ is partially differentiable with respect to $x$ and $y$ at $(0,0)$. For which $n$ is it true that f is differentiable at $(0,0)$? Find the value of derivative at $(0,0)$？

Since $x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta$), I tried to replace $f(r\cos(\theta),rsin(\theta))=r^n \cos(\theta)$ by <s>$\require{enclose}
    \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f(x,y)=x(x^2+y^2)^{n-3}}$</s> $\color{red}{(f(x,y)=x(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}),}$ then computed the partial derivative by definition directly. I'm not sure if this process is right or not.

Comment: $r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}.$ Hence $f(x,y)=x(x^2+y^2)^{(n-1)/2}.$ Your approach is fine.

Comment: The process is right but your algebra is wrong, $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ so what is $q$ in $r^n=(x^2+y^2)^q$? 

It's not $n-3$.

Comment: Thanks. I just fixed it.

Comment: $f(0,0) = (0,0)$?

Comment: @Paul Frost Sorry, a typo, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is completely correct! To calculate the partial derinatives use $f(0,0)=0$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{h(h^{2})^{\dfrac{n-1}{2}}}{h}=\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}h^{n-1}=0$ for $\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$

and $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{0-0}{h}=0$

for  $\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$